# Is there a way to recursively unwrap a function type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, compiler-errors, unwrap, inferred-type

Let's say we have the following type `I`:

```
type I = () => () => () => "a" | "b" | "c";
```

Is there a way to create a generic type `Unwrap` such that `Unwrap<I>` evaluates to `"a" | "b" | "c"`?

```
type I = () => () => () => "a" | "b" | "c";

type Result = Unwrap<I>; // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

The following (ofc) produces a circularity error:

```
type Unwrap<
  T extends (...args: any[]) => any,
  R = ReturnType<T>
> = R extends (...args: any[]) => any
  ? Unwrap<R>
  : R;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There may be a workaround you can use now, but the good news is that in TypeScript 4.1.0 (when it releases), your code will work as-is! [Here is the PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) that adds support for recursive conditional types. You can even try it out if you use the "nightly" option on the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200824#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkjAvDAFASiQPlRx31YwBEAhkTAD7EBG5VRAxkQNzCiSwCqAdgO4BOJCAB4AKtmSiYUAB4go3ACYBnVADoNJfgHNlALhgluYANoBdXNgCW3AGZR+MTjAD8TvoJGdsB0a3bQMABKUMoArgA2IEjuAkLCcJjMMAD0KcRklDR0xExswEA).

Comment: In my opinion the workarounds are so awful that I'd just start using `typescript@next` unless you have some absolute need otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here's the hack which works in TypeScript 3. It's actually not that awful.

```
type I = () => (() => (() => "a" | "b" | "c")) | "e" | (() => "f" | "g");

type Unwrap<T> =
    T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R
        ? { 0: Unwrap<R> }[T extends any ? 0 : never] // Hack to recurse.
    : T;

type Result = Unwrap<I>;
// type Result = "e" | "a" | "b" | "c" | "f" | "g";
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAklC8UAUBKBA+ZqNbfTARAIYFQA+UBARqRQQMYEpp0S244EBm7BA5kwDcAKGGhIUAKoA7AO4AnImAA8AFUzxhUbVFVQIAD2ARpAEwDOyAHQ2i8vuYBcUItJABtALp5MAS2lcEPJQAEpaOhEA-FAA3lAADM4yCkrKIZgAvu56hsZmlq4gUNHxUM7SEABuQZ5QAPR1UAASRPQA1lDAAPZQ8hD0AK7y5hBW4drOqiJi4NAhEOYDADbACFJyiiow6CINnbOhC8uriARs5JQkF9S8jNc81wIiQA)

Answer (score 1):

As listed in the comment above, the `Unwrap` type works in TypeScript 4.1 (soon-to-be released).